# pause html5 video when scrolling starts

Tags: javascript, html5-video, scrolltop

I recently added a html5 video to my own company website. imbeeld.nl

Now I want the video to pause when ones starts scrolling the page.

I know this can be done by adding some JS, but I'm quite new to this.

```
document.getElementById('myvideotag').pause();
```

I allready made some script for replacing the video's CSS class when scrolling begins:

```
$(document).on("scroll",function(){
  if($(document).scrollLeft()>1)    
    {$("#frontvideo").removeClass("front_cover").addClass("front_cover_hide");}
  else{$("#frontvideo").removeClass("front_cover_hide").addClass("front_cover");}
});
```

How to combine both JS parts and pause the video when scrolling begins?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Whats the problem just to combine it?
If you wont to pause video on any scroll:

```
$(document).on("scroll",function(){
    document.getElementById('myvideotag').pause();
    if($(document).scrollLeft()>1{
        $("#frontvideo").removeClass("front_cover").addClass("front_cover_hide");
    }
    else{
        $("#frontvideo").removeClass("front_cover_hide").addClass("front_cover");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define by variable

like

```
var video = document.getElementById("myvideotag");
```

and then you can use to pause like when scroll begin

```
video.pause();
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to achieve is to hide and to pause the video when the user scroll to the left, here you have an snippet with a video example from wikimedia.

BTW, you can use `$('#myvideotag')[0]` to pull a DOM object from a jQuery one.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myvideotag')[0].play();
});

$(document).on("scroll",function(){
  if($(document).scrollLeft()>1)    
   {      
     $("#frontvideo").removeClass("front_cover").addClass("front_cover_hide");
     $('#myvideotag')[0].pause();
   }
   else
   {
    $("#frontvideo").removeClass("front_cover_hide").addClass("front_cover");
     $('#myvideotag')[0].play();
   }
});
```

```css
html, body
{
  width: 110%;
  height: 100%;
}

#frontvideo
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 110%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.front_cover
{
  opacity: 0;
}

.front_cover_hide
{
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<video id="myvideotag" width="400" controls>
  <source src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/4/4d/Wikipedia_Edit_2014.webm/Wikipedia_Edit_2014.webm.480p.webm" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>


<div id="frontvideo" class="front_cover">I'M THE COVER</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $(document).on("scroll",function(){
            var sc = $("body").prop('scrollLeft')
            var scv= $("#myvideotag").offset().Left;
            if(scv < sc)    
            {
                $("#frontvideo").removeClass("front_cover").addClass("front_cover_hide");
            }
            else{
                 $("#frontvideo").removeClass("front_cover_hide").addClass("front_cover");
            }

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It works!
this does the trick:
sorry for the bad layout

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#frontvideo')[0].play();
});

$(document).on("scroll",function(){
  if($(document).scrollLeft()>1){      
     $('#frontvideo')[0].pause();
   }
   else
   {
     $('#frontvideo')[0].play();
   }
});
```